# Normalised Liouville Measure on $\Gamma / PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: matrices, measure-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, geodesic, modular-group

Let $\Gamma$ be a normal subgroup of finite index of the modular group $PSL(2, \mathbb{Z})$.

What does **Normalised Liouville Measure on $\Gamma / PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$** mean?

Suggesting a reference is highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know what Liouville measure means in any context, besides "normalized Liouville measure on $\Gamma / PSL(2,\mathbb R)$? For example, do you know what Liouville measure on $PSL(2,\mathbb R)$ means?

Comment: @LeeMosher Do you mean by Liouville measure on $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$ the one that is induced by hyperbolic volume measure on $T^1(\mathbb{H})$?

Comment: Yes, that's right, although I've not heard the measure on $T^1(\mathbb H)$ referred to as "hyperbolic volume measure".